# How to arrange rows selected in MYSQL query?

Tags: mysql, primary-key, order-by, cursors

I'm fetching data from a table "TABLE_A", it's having Primary Key as "PK_ONE" (which is unsigned INT) .

I'm fetching data from "TABLE_A" with where clause on PK_ONE ; 
Ex: SELECT PK_ONE from TABLE_A where PK_ONE in (2,88,3999,4,282,33399,1,394);

When I'm using dataset mentioned above in PHP cursor; I want to ensure that data fetched comes in the sequence of values of "PK_ONE" in WHERE clause.

Can you please give me some direction to achieve same? [Currently rows are coming in asending order]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for `ORDER BY FIELD()`, and it looks like this:

```
SELECT 
  PK_ONE 
from 
  TABLE_A 
where 
  PK_ONE in (2,88,3999,4,282,33399,1,394)
ORDER BY
  FIELD (PK_ONE, 2,88,3999,4,282,33399,1,394)
```

[`FIELD()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_field) is a function which returns the position of an element (first argument) in a list of values (2nd, 3rd, ... arguments).

So you need to generate/template the list of values twice for this query.